# Why is my question on martingales off-topic and not migrated?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic, migration, close-reasons

Here is my question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/225181/show-that-ex-t-t-infty-le-ex-0-and-cp-sup-x-n-ge-c-le-ex-0

I said in the beginning to please migrate if needed. Could it be on-topic here if I made some edits? What should I do?

Comment: I asked on [math.se] that you try to avoid things like "w/" in posts. That this is desirable applies even more strongly on this site. Needless to say, you do as you like. But I assure you the general tolerance on this site towards things like this is quite limited.

Comment: Oh okay thanks @quid ^-^

Comment: I'm not sure what the standards are on Math.SE, but I'd guess you need to improve the exposition of your question to make people seriously look at it.

Comment: @StefanKohl What do you mean?

Comment: @BCLC: For example, avoid abbreviations (pls, /w, , myb etc.), text posted as picture, excessively long formulas / chains of (in)equalities and bad line breaks and -indentations.

Comment: Oooohhh okay thanks @StefanKohl ^-^ About the last 3, what do you mean exactly? W/c i mean which parts?

Comment: @BCLC: I can't teach you mathematical writing in a few comments here, but it will certainly help you firstly to look how well-received questions are written, and secondly, to ask yourself how a question of somebody else needs to be written such that you would enjoy reading it and be motivated to answer.

Comment: @StefanKohl: the poster should (in theory) be well aware about the standards on [math.se], having been informed about them at considerable length there. The receptiveness of them to such can be inferred by extrapolating the fact that they used "W/c" in reply to a comment telling them not to use such abbreviations.

Comment: @quid I was just kidding. :|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not an expert on the topic, so I can't tell if the question could be edited to make it on-topic.
Typically questions that ask for homework help are not received well here, but exceptions are possible.
It seems to me that the question would be fine at MSE and could have been migrated, but others may disagree.

People who vote to close are often hesitant to vote to migrate.
We don't want to migrate questions that are not warmly accepted at their new home, so in event of any uncertainty people often decide not to migrate.
If you feel that your question was not asked in the right place but would work well in a new one, you can ask for a migration by flagging the question and explaining the situation.
And you can always delete your question and ask it at MSE instead.

Comment: @BCLC, you are welcome! If you want to read more about closing and migrating here, this meta discussion might be a good place to start: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2319/55893