# How about a way to flag a question for migration to another site without down voting it

Tags: discussion, migration, down-votes

If the question is valid, it seems churlish to down-vote it, especially since doing so affects the user's reputation adversely. Sure, it's a mistake to ask a question on the wrong SE site, but I don't think it should be a punishable one.

Comment: Flagging for migration does not automatically cause you to downvote, so I am really not sure what you are asking.

Comment: If I understand correctly what I read in some threads on meta.SE, downvotes are removed after the question is migrated, upvotes from the original sites are kept. You can find further information here and in other related posts: [Reset votes on migrated questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87031).

Comment: A very recent example, a question [received two downvotes on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/294664/timeline), then it was migrated, [the migrated version](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2682006/timeline) has (at the moment) no upvotes and no downvotes

Comment: @MartinSleziak, thanks for the clarification. It was indeed the recent question on MO that prompted my own here. Personally I think it's poor form to down-vote a question for no other reason than it needs to be migrated. I'm glad down-votes are at least removed when this is done..

Comment: Actually I have the problem that sometimes I want to vote to a question for migration, but this accounts as a closing vote too, so if 3 other people vote to close it, I'll be part of those who closed the question. This is absurd.

Comment: By the way given that after clicking close, the option between "See MathSE for general questions..." and migration, which first requires clicking on "The question belongs on another site", is not very transparent; at least it was initially unclear to me. One reason being that as non-native English speaker, I didn't know the distinction "belongs to"/ "belongs on".

Comment: @YCor I will just add link to older discussion which is related to the issues you raised in your last two comments: [Migrating to Math.SE: too many close reasons](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2319) I have posted a few more links [in MathOverflow chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9369/2018/3/10) - I chose to post them there since I do not want to start long comment exchange about something which is not directly related to this question.

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks! I was going to say that I was not aware of the first link but I did a comment there 3 years ago. Most likely the problem will not be solved and it will be discussed somewhere else in 3 years :)

Comment: The question seems to be predicated on a false premise that the users of MO are of one mind and act in a coordinated way. So, some user thinks that the question would be a better fit elsewhere and votes to migrate, while another user thinks it's just a crappy question and downvotes it. One doesn't know about the other. How, exactly, would you expect these differences in opinion and in action to be prevented?